# Is it possible to implement the Palatini formalism in xAct?

Tags: xact

In the Palatini formalism, the connections $\Gamma^\alpha_{\beta\gamma}$ are considered independent variable togheter with the metric; as a consequence Ricci and Rieman tensors corresponding to the metric are usually different from the ones corresponding the the connections.

Is it possible to implement the Palatini formalism in xAct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, and it's actually easy to do so. For example the following code will perform variation respect to Christoffel symbol for the Einstein-Hilbert Lagrangian

```
Lag = Sqrt[-Detmetric[]] RicciScalarCD[]
LagChris =Lag // RiemannToChristoffel
VarD[ChristoffelCD[-a, b, c], CD][%]
% // ContractMetric // ToCanonical // Simplify;
christoffelvar = %/Sqrt[-Detmetric[]]
```